# Is there a cleaner way to organize this recoilJS state?

Tags: recoiljs

I've just learned about [recoilJS](https://recoiljs.org) and have been playing around with it a bit and have a question about whether what I've done is considered "correct."  My code works, but it feels weird.

I've got the following React function component:

```
export const TimerPanel: FC = () => {
  const gameState = useRecoilValue<GameState>(HeaderAtoms.gameState);
  const timerCount = useRecoilValue(HeaderAtoms.timerCount);
  const setTimerCounter = useSetRecoilState(HeaderAtoms.timerCounter);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (gameState === GameState.IN_PROGRESS && timerCount < 1000) {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        setTimerCounter(timerCount + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
  });

  return <NumberPanel num={timerCount} />;
};
```

where the relevant atom and selector are defined as:

```
export const timerCount = atom<number>({
  key: 'Header.timerCount',
  default: 0
});

export const timerCounter = selector<number>({
  key: 'Header.timerCounter',
  get: ({ get }) => {
    return get(timerCount);
  },
  set: ({ get, set }, newCount) => {
    if (get(gameState) === GameState.NEW) {
      set(timerCount, 0);
    } else if (get(gameState) === GameState.IN_PROGRESS) {
      set(timerCount, newCount);
    }
  }
});
```

Basically, when the game starts, the `TimerPanel` increments the timer display by `1` every second the game is in progress.  If the user resets the game (`GameState.NEW`), `timerCount` resets back to zero.  If the atom/selector aren't done properly, there's a race condition in that the game state and timer count will reset, but the timer is still going and will still update the `TimerPanel` one more time.  This is why I have the `if` blocks in my selector's `set` prop.

Basically, I'm concerned that my `timerCounter` selector is a glorified filter/pass-thru entity for the `timerCount` state and am wondering if there's a better way to handle this use case.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is the race condition, in your code, I don't see how your timer would click. setTimeout will tick once.

Anyway, you have 2 states, game state and timer state. You want to reset timer when game state changes. How about doing it in a game state selector? or move the logic into a custom hook and operate on these 2 states directly.

Comment: So the race condition is mitigated by my `if` blocks because the game state value determines the timer value.  But the timer could actually be in progress when the state changes so there's no really any way to cancel it.

All that aside, I REALLY like your idea of using hooks here to encapsulate the calls.  That feels really clean and the "right" way to do that here.  Thanks!.